# Raspberry Pi console mode - can not open Luakit

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

When I try to open Luakit browser on Raspberry Pi (in console mode), I get this message:

```
(luakit:623): Gtk-warning **: cannot open display:
```

Does anyone know is it even possible to open luakit browser when raspberry pi is in console mode? 
I wonder how other programs like OMX player can run in console mode, but luakit can't. On startup I call simple python script where I call luakit browser with subprocess command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["luakit","google.com"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. Instead of running my python script in console mode, I changed autostart file located in directory:

```
/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi
```

and added line to execute my python script which is working with Luakit browser:

```
sudo python myScript.py
```

This way, raspberry is starting normally in display mode, and after 1-2 seconds my python script is running Luakit without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

`luakit --display=:0` (or 1 or whatever your display is)

Comment: tried with 

    p = subprocess.Popen(["luakit", "--display=:0", "google.com"])

got same error message